# Disable CSS stylesheet for a specific action in Symfony

Tags: css, symfony1

Is there any way of disabling a stylesheet in view.yml for a specific action in Symfony?

For example I've got this in my view.yml:

```
default:
  stylesheets:    [default.css]
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
displaySuccess:
  stylesheet: [!default.css]
```

to disable default.css in displaySuccess only

Is this possible or do I have to explicitly say which modules/actions should have default.css?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can remove or add stylesheets to a modules view.yml by doing the following:

```
displaySuccess:
  stylesheet: [-default]
```

would remove default.css from the display action. Simply putting

```
displaySuccess:
  stylesheet: [-*]
```

would remove all stylesheets.

Comment: I didn't find this in the (now legacy) docs. It really should be. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

to remove for example, unecessary  /sfDoctrinePlugin/css/default.css, now you can overwrite the backend styles with your own!

maybe put it into yout layout.php:

```
<?php sfContext::getInstance()->getResponse()->removeStylesheet('/sfDoctrinePlugin/css/global.css'); ?>

<?php sfContext::getInstance()->getResponse()->removeStylesheet('/sfDoctrinePlugin/css/default.css'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain, but I believe the compiled view.yml file is processed before execution of the action. If that's true, you can do:

```
public function executeDisplay()
{
  $this->response->removeStylesheet('default.css');
}
```

I find view.yml to be a little inflexible. You may find it easier to have a global "head" template that gets included in your layout(s). Then you can check sfConfig values to see if you should include individual files, making it easier to turn them on and off.

Comment: No that doesn't work, but I think you're right about including it in the <head> on the template, because I'm using a different layout for that action anyway