# Removing a stylesheet for a specific template

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable CSS stylesheet for a specific action in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325789/disable-css-stylesheet-for-a-specific-action-in-symfony)

I would like to remove one stylesheet from the response object for a specific template. I am trying to accomplish it like this:

My view.yml (excerpt):

```
stylesheets:    [main.css, forms.css, jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css]
```

The layout (empty.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include_http_metas() ?>
        <?php include_metas() ?>
        <?php include_title() ?>
        <?php include_stylesheets() ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $sf_content ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the action (excerpt):

```
$response = $this->getResponse();
$response->removeStylesheet("main.css");

$this->setLayout("empty");
```

However, the `main.css` file is still included in the generated html. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Correct, haven't seen it before posting but it's a nearly exact duplicate. Voted to close.